# Formatting an expression in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having problems formatting this expression to be a number in SSRS. I can't seem to use the normal formatting using the wizard so I've tried formatting the expression I've made for the textbox.

Here is the expression

```
   =lookup( 2, Fields!RowNumber.Value,  Format(Fields!Money.Value, "N"), "DataSource1")
```

I'm expecting back a comma seperated number but all I'm getting back is N. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

`Format(Fields!Money.Value,"#,##0.00")`

My code will always show 0.00 if there's nothing. But you could just use #.

Answer (score 0):

Please use #,# as the format string.